# Showing contextual documentation for C++ virtual functions in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-assist

Is there a way to annotate a virtual function so that Visual Studio will show documentation from the function's base declaration on all its implementations?

I'm imagining something of this form:

```
class Base
{
    // [some documentation, probably with markup]
    virtual void SomeMethod() = 0;
};

// [some markup here if need be]
void Derived::SomeMethod()
{
    ...
}
```

My desired result is that, when viewing **Derived::SomeMethod**, the documentation in **Base** is easily accessible - for instance displayed as mouse-over hover help, or instantly, reliably, navigable to.

I'm happy to use Visual Assist, or some other plug-in, if need be.

The wider goal is to help people working with interfaces in a large project, where it's important to understand how the framework will call your method. Conventional Visual Studio navigation gets swamped by the numerous implementations of each interface. I haven't had any success getting IntelliSense, or Visual Assist, to help out with this.